# Плавный ползунок прокрутке в слайдере Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всегда использовал плагин http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ для создания слайдеров, но сейчас столкнулся с такой задачей - нужно сделать плавный ползуноок скролинга слайдов, как на скрине.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать. Если покажите примером - будет вообще идеально.

У меня была мысль связать https://jqueryui.com/slider/ , но не знаю, как это сделать.

Comment: Может быть все же не слайдер, а горизонтальная прокрутка. http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ в помощь

Comment: Или тут не нужен слайдер, а нужна просто горизонтальная прокрутка или можно стилизовать булиты, под то, что надо

Comment: Точно, спасибо!) Как-то не пришла мысль на этот счет

Comment: Оформите ответом, отмечу как правильный :)